# Use the result of a function as a radio button's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, radio-button

I am trying to use the value/result of a function as my radio button value but I can't seem to get it right.

In the below form, I want to use the result of 'calcDogecoins()' to become the value of the radio button. I then go on to email this value to myself with php.

```
<form name="buynow" method="post" action="send_form_email.php"> 
  <input type="radio" name="cardamount" value="" onclick="calcDogecoins()">Choose Gift Card Value<br>
</form>
```

This is the associated function that I want to become the value of the button. This function takes the user input, multiplies it by a value pulled from an API and returns the calculated live price of Dogecoin.

```
<script>
function calcDogecoins() {
  var resultedDogecoins;

  var giftValue = prompt("What Value Gift Card Would You Like To Purchase?", "");

  if (giftValue != null) {


    // constants
    var valueEntered = 1;
    var ONE_DOGE = '1 DOGE = ';
    var ONE_USD = '$' + valueEntered + ' gift card costs: ';

    // cryptsy's public API for DOGE, mtgox's for BTC
    var dogeApiUrl = 'http%3A%2F%2Fpubapi.cryptsy.com%2Fapi.php%3Fmethod%3Dsinglemarketdata%26marketid%3D132';
    var btcApiUrl = 'http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker_fast';

    // node cross domain proxy server
    var jsonPWrapper = 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?callback=?&url=';

    $.getJSON(jsonPWrapper + dogeApiUrl, function(data) {
      var dogePrice = data.
      return .markets.DOGE.lasttradeprice;
      $("div.btc").html(ONE_DOGE + 'B' + dogePrice);

      $.getJSON(jsonPWrapper + btcApiUrl, function(data) {
        var btcPrice = data.
        return .buy.value;
        $("div.usd").html(ONE_DOGE + '$' + btcPrice * dogePrice);
        var dogecost = (Math.floor(((((1 / (btcPrice * dogePrice))*1.05) * valueEntered) * 100) / 100));

        //var finalAmount = (dogecost * enteredAmount);
        //alert(finalAmount); 


        resultedDogecoins = "The cost of a $" + giftValue + " gift card is " + giftValue * dogecost + " Dogecoins.";
        document.getElementById("doges").innerHTML = resultedDogecoins;



      });
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would a radio button have a value, it's either checked or not checked ?

Comment: If you're looking to set the "value" of a radio button, you might want to do it with a label as a sibling to the radio button. If you dont mean the text related to the radio button, please tell us what you need.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. In the following line: <input type="radio" name="cardamount" value="" onclick="calcDogecoins()">, I want the 'value=""' to become what 'calcDogecoins()' is calculating. I want this form to submit me the live value of dogecoins. The reason it is a radio button is because I also have other options that are set amounts, like $5 and 10$.

Comment: I am not familiar with siblings to radio buttons. I will have to look into that as, yes, I am trying to set the value based on my function. I don't want the value to be the same everytime - it changes every time it is selected.

Comment: I would keep radio button with a static value, for example "1" and when the calculation is done you update a hidden input with its value, when form is submitted you check if the radio button value that was submitted says it must be the calculated value and then you retrieve the value from the hidden input if so